# vb6 client and server using playyit.gg multiplay lan host detect

Tags: networking, lan, vb6

i used this https://github.com/dechamps/WinIPBroadcast it is a .exe made by the author of this tool that WinIPBroadcast is a small program that allows Windows applications to send global IP broadcast packets (destination address 255.255.255.255) to all interfaces instead of just the preferred one.

when I run multiplayer game offline lan on main pc and Windows Sandbox while WinIPBroadcast  is running on main pc i am able to see the lan host in-game multiplayer section.

if I don't use WinIPBroadcast then in the main pc in-game I cant see hosted game from Windows Sandbox.

i have a client and server made and I have the server.exe on my pc, the listening port is set to 12345.

client, it uses the playyit.gg ip:port ahan-vampire.at.playit.gg:44844
I changed the value to IP and port for privacy reasons.

from Windows Sandbox my client is able to connect to my main pc using those playyit.gg  ip:port over the internet and the main question now is if I run WinIPBroadcast  on both sides will I be able to see the lan-hosted game on my main pc?